# Who are the most inspiring WOMEN communicators of math for a general audience?

Tags: soft-question

This is a follow up to my [earlier question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265763/who-are-the-most-inspiring-communicators-of-math-for-a-general-audience/)

I'd like to improve the gender balance of my podcast series. (I interview people who are inspired by math and are inspiring others.) Through no conscious intention I've interviewed mostly men. I'm looking for suggestions on women to interview who are helping to popularize math.

Names that come to mind are Julie Rehmeyer, Evelyn Lamb, Danica McKellar, Vi Hart, and Erica Klarreich.

Who else do you know, famous or not, who I should try to get for my series? These women don't need to be professional writers. They can be game designers, teachers, toy makers, bloggers or anyone who has made a big contribution to helping kids or adults enjoy math more.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Tanya Khovanova. Here is her homepage [Tanya Khovanova](http://www.tanyakhovanova.com/)